# Converting Struct to CSV string

Tags: csv, go

I have a struct that gets Scanned in after a DB response like the below. Each field is the same len(). I'd like to take this struct and produce a CSV delimited string/

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Data struct {
    id   []string
    col1 []float64
    col2 []float64
}

func main() {
    d := &Data{
        id:   []string{"id_1", "id_1", "id_1", "id_1"},
        col1: []float64{340.384926, 321.385028, 520.341473, 500.385473},
        col2: []float64{123.285031, 4087.284675, -8958.284216, -7612.283668},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", d)
}
```

I'd like to loop through the struct which I believe is possible using `reflect`, then construct a CSV string like the following using the struct field names as the header and t he values as individual columns for that header, delimited by a comma.

```
`
id,col1,col2
id_1,340.384926,123.285031
id_1,321.385028,4087.284675
id_1,520.341473,-8958.284216
id_1,500.385473,-7612.283668
`
```

What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, avoid using `reflect` to iterate through struct because it can result in *decreased performance* and *reduced code readability*. Don't fall for the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - the ask here is to transform `Data` struct into csv string (Y problem), but the X problem here is avoid using struct type such as `Data` as starting point.

Many golang packages that manipulate csv prefer:

- `[][]string`: [encoding/csv](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#NewReader) and [struct2csv](https://github.com/mohae/struct2csv)
- `[]Struct{}`: [gocsv](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) and [csv2struct](https://github.com/Koshqua/csv2struct)

However, if `Data` type is unavoidable, you can first write a function that transforms `Data` into `[][]string` while avoiding using `reflect`:

```
func TransformDataTo2DSlice(d Data) [][]string {

    numRows := len(d.id)
    result := make([][]string, numRows+1)

    // Add header row
    result[0] = []string{"id", "col1", "col2"}

    // Add data rows
    for i := 0; i < numRows; i++ {
        result[i+1] = []string{d.id[i],
            strconv.FormatFloat(d.col1[i], 'f', -1, 64),
            strconv.FormatFloat(d.col2[i], 'f', -1, 64),
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Next, use `w.WriteAll()` method from `encoding/csv` to easily transform `[][]string` to csv

```
func main() {

    d := Data{
        id:   []string{"id_1", "id_1", "id_1", "id_1"},
        col1: []float64{340.384926, 321.385028, 520.341473, 500.385473},
        col2: []float64{123.285031, 4087.284675, -8958.284216, -7612.283668},
    }

    d2dslice := TransformDataTo2DSlice(d)

    // fmt.Printf("%+v", d2dslice)
    // [[id, col1, col2],
    // [id_1, 340.384926, 123.285031],
    // [id_1, 321.385028, 4087.284675],
    // [id_1, 520.341473, -8958.284216],
    // [id_1,500.385473,-7612.283668]]

    w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    w.WriteAll(d2dslice)

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error writing csv:", err)
    }

    // stdout:
    // id,col1,col2
    // id_1,340.384926,123.285031
    // id_1,321.385028,4087.284675
    // id_1,520.341473,-8958.284216
    // id_1,500.385473,-7612.283668
}
```

Run the program above here: [go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/PM_CTlvmmAm)

To write csv to a string variable instead, pass in a buffer:

```
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w := csv.NewWriter(buf)
    w.WriteAll(d2dslice)

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error writing csv:", err)
    }

    csvString := buf.String()

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", csvString)  // print the variable type
    // string

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", csvString) // print the variable value
    // id,col1,col2
    // id_1,340.384926,123.285031
    // id_1,321.385028,4087.284675
    // id_1,520.341473,-8958.284216
    // id_1,500.385473,-7612.283668
```

Comment: Great answer. The data comes from a ```rows.Scan()``` which is why I stuck with using struct for simplicity. I can look into reading that result into a different data type like you mentioned. However, your answer writes the data to ```stdout```. Is there a way to save the result in a string variable within memory instead of printing to ```stdout```?

Comment: updated my answer to reflect your request. :) @Coldchain9

Answer (score 2):

use golang package **encoding/csv**.

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv.

Comment: If I don't want to write it to an actual CSV file, just want to maintain the string in memory, which utility would I use from the package?

Comment: `csv.NewWriter` takes anything which implements `io.Writer` as an argument. Try using it with a `strings.Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Convert the data structure into a 2-dimensional array `[][]string`
- Step 2: Print the result of the 2-dimensional array.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Data struct {
    Id   []string  `json:"id"`
    Col1 []float64 `json:"col1"`
    Col2 []float64 `json:"col2"`
}

func (d *Data) String() string {
    dataType := reflect.TypeOf(*d)
    dataValue := reflect.ValueOf(*d)

    // Step 1: Convert the data structure into a 2-dimensional array.
    var result [][]string // [col][how many 'row' on each col]
    for col := 0; col < dataType.NumField(); col++ {
        filedType := dataType.Field(col)
        filedValue := dataValue.Field(col)

        if result == nil {
            colMax := dataType.NumField()
            result = make([][]string, colMax)
        }

        var rowMax int
        switch filedValue.Interface().(type) {
        case []string:
            rowMax = len(filedValue.Interface().([]string))
        case []float64:
            rowMax = len(filedValue.Interface().([]float64))
        default:
            log.Fatalf("not support type. %v", filedValue.Interface())
        }
        if result[col] == nil {
            result[col] = make([]string, rowMax+1) // 1 for header
        }

        // header
        result[col][0] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", filedType.Tag.Get("json"))

        // data
        var cell any
        for row := 1; row <= rowMax; row++ {
            switch filedValue.Interface().(type) {
            case []string:
                cell = filedValue.Interface().([]string)[row-1]
            case []float64:
                cell = filedValue.Interface().([]float64)[row-1]
            default:
                log.Fatalf("not support type. %v", filedValue.Interface())
            }
            result[col][row] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", cell)
        }
    }

    // Step 2: Print the result of the 2-dimensional array.
    str := ""
    const sep = ","
    for row := 0; row < len(result[0]); row++ {
        for col := 0; col < len(result); col++ {
            str += fmt.Sprintf("%v", result[col][row])
            if col < len(result)-1 {
                str += sep
            }
        }
        if row < len(result[0])-1 {
            str += "\n"
        }
    }
    return str
}

func main() {
    d := &Data{
        Id:   []string{"id_1", "id_1", "id_1", "id_1"},
        Col1: []float64{340.384926, 321.385028, 520.341473, 500.385473},
        Col2: []float64{123.285031, 4087.284675, -8958.284216, -7612.283668},
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

output:

```
id,col1,col2
id_1,340.384926,123.285031  
id_1,321.385028,4087.284675 
id_1,520.341473,-8958.284216
id_1,500.385473,-7612.283668
```

<kbd>[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/aDMz9LHjweH)</kbd>